# Gerar contas em lote apresentando data corrompida

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite a todos, estou desenvolvendo um projeto em que eu gero contas em lote dependendo da quantidade de meses que o usuário seleciona sendo no máximo 12 meses, ok o CRUD dessas contas, já esta funcionando perfeitamente, criei um for que conta quantos meses é pra ser gerado a conta e vai somando +1 Mês á data de vencimento, o primeiro vencimento sai legal, porém as próximas datas aparecem truncadas parece segue o trecho do código de gerar em lote e a exibição dos registros na tela

TRECHO DO CÓDIGO

```
    public function gerarLote($meses){

    $conexao = new Conexao();

    $vencer = new DateTime($this->getVenc());

    for ($i=0; $i < $meses; $i++) { 

    $this->insert();

    $vencer->modify('+1 month');

    $this->setVenc($vencer->format("d/m/Y"));

    }

    return true;
}
```

Exibição dos registros na tela com referência a "MENSALIDADE JIU"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Criei esta classe para utilizar para casos como este seu, em que temos que manipular data.

```
/**
 * Responsavel pela manupulação de datas e horas no sistema.
 * @author Luis Alberto Batista Pedroso <b2005.luis@gmail.com>
 * @version 20180730-202911
 */
class Calendario {

    /**
     * Data do calendário.
     * @var DateTime Uma instancia de DateTime.
     */
    private $Data;

    /**
     * Retorna a data do calendário.
     * @return DateTime Uma instancia de DateTime.
     */
    public function getData() {
        return $this->Data;
    }

    /**
     * Define a data do calendário.
     * @param DateTime $data Uma instancia de DateTime.
     */
    public function setData($data) {
        // Zona geografica padrão.
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
        // Criar nova data.
        switch ($data) {
            case is_string($data):
                $timestamp = strtotime($data);
                break;

            case is_object($data) && is_a($data, "DateTime"):
                $timestamp = $data->getTimestamp();
                break;

            default:
                $timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
                break;
        }
        // Definir objeto data.
        $nData = new DateTime();
        $nData->setTimestamp($timestamp);
        // Definir data do objeto.
        $this->Data = $nData;
    }

    /**
     * Inicaliza um objeto da classe Calendario com a Data e hora do sistema no fuso horario Ameri/Sao_Paulo.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Zona geografica padrão.
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
        // inicializar data/hora.
        $this->setData(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o numero de dias de um mês com base em um Mês e Ano informados.
     * @return int Um numero inteiro com o total de dias do mês solicitado.
     */
    public function numeroDiasNoMes() {
        $iMes = (int) $this->Data->format("m");
        $iAno = (int) $this->Data->format("Y");
        return cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $iMes, $iAno);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona horas ao horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de horas a adicionar.
     */
    public function adicionarHoras($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}H");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remover horas do horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de horas a remover.
     */
    public function removerHoras($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}H");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona minutos ao horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de minutos a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function adicionarMinutos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}I");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remover minutos do horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de minutos a ser removido.
     */
    public function removerMinutos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}I");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona segundos ao horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de segundos a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function adicionarSegundos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}S");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remove segundos do horario atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de segundos a ser removido.
     */
    public function removerSegundos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("PT{$valor}S");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona Dias a data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de dias a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function adicionarDias($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}D");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remove Dias da data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de dias a ser removido.
     */
    public function removerDias($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}D");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona Meses a data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de meses a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function adicionarMeses($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}M");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remove Meses da data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de meses a ser removido.
     */
    public function removerMeses($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}M");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona Anos a data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de anos a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function adicionarAnos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}Y");
        $this->Data->add($nInterval);
    }

    /**
     * Remove Anos da data atual do objeto.
     * @param int $valor Um numero inteiro com a quantidade de anos a ser adicionado.
     */
    public function removerAnos($valor) {
        $nInterval = new DateInterval("P{$valor}Y");
        $this->Data->sub($nInterval);
    }

}
```

Exemplo genérico de utilização:

```
$meses = 6;

$_DataVenc = new Calendario();
$_DataVenc->setData("2018-10-15");
print($_DataVenc->getData()->format("d/m/Y")."<br>");
// 1º Cadastre a primeira data guardada em _DataVenc...

// Percorra cadastrando as demias...
for($i=0; $i<$meses; $i++) {
    $_DataVenc->adicionarMeses(1);
    print($_DataVenc->getData()->format("d/m/Y")."<br>");
    // Cadastre o novo vencimento guardado em _DataVenc.
}:
```

> 15/10/2018 
>   15/11/2018 
>   15/12/2018 
>   15/01/2019 
>   15/02/2019 
>   15/03/2019 
>   15/04/2019

Comment: fiquei meio perdido onde eu coloco isso? quando eu pego o dado do formulário eu pego como datetime?  e o meu get não é assim getData() eu teria que colocar dentro do parenteses

Comment: eu seto o getVenc() assim? 

$this->setVenc(print($_DataVenc->getData()->format("d/m/Y")."<br>"));

e instancio na função gerarLote() 

$vencer = new Calendario();

$_DataVenc->setData("2018-10-15");

a primeira data tem que ficar separada das demais fora do for?

Comment: Luiz Alberto  deixei a função gerarLote(); dessa forma

  `  public function gerarLote($meses){

        $conexao = new Conexao();

        $vencer = new Calendario();

        $vencer->setData("2020-01-07");

        $this->setVenc($vencer->getData()->format("d/m/Y"));

        for ($i=0; $i < $meses; $i++) { 

        $this->insert();
        
        $vencer->adicionarMeses(1);

        }

        return true;
    }  `

Comment: não consigo colocar meu código formatado nos comentários queria colocar a imagem também do que o Luis Alberto orientou

Comment: da ERRO que não posso armazenar um objeto DateTime como uma string

Comment: É possível colocar imagem nos comentários? muito complicado de mexer aqui :(

Comment: Pessoal, consegui resolver de uma forma bem simples sete o format dessa forma

$this->setVenc($vencer->format(\DateTime::ISO8601));

fica registrado aí a solução pra se alguem passar por este problema AGAIN